# Can i use table column in Sqlite database as a resource variable?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

i have some code like this

Orignally:

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
```

And the videoView works perfectly.

Then I changed the code into

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + Dbhelper.COLUMN_Path;

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
```

I stored "R.raw.video" into the COLUMN.Path in the database. It works. But why the videoView doesnt work? It told me "Cant play this video"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored the integer value of `R.raw.video` then this is an integer number that the system assigned the this resource video file when the project was compiled. 
I believe you retrieved it at runtime and saved it to the db. 
This integer value is valid as long as you use the apk built at the time of that compilation. 
**But** if you make any changes (especially to your resources) and recompile, there is no guarantee that this value will still be valid and correspond to this resource, because resource values may be reassigned new values.  
So your way is wrong.  
One way to solve this issue is to store in the db the string "name" of the resource, meaning: `"video"` (not the fully qualified `R.raw.video`).  
Now when you want to retrieve the file from the `raw` folder, 
after you get the value from the db to a variable like `videoName`, do this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(videoName, "raw", getPackageName());
```

This is the way to retrieve the integer id of the resource named `videoName` which resides in the `raw` folder.  
 
If your code is not inside an activity you need to supply a valid `Context`, like this:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(videoName, "raw", context.getPackageName());
```

and finally:

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + id;
```

**Edit**
If you stored `R.raw.video` as a string in db, then this cannot help you because this full string has no value assigned to it as I explained earlier.

Comment: I completely do as you said, but still it doesn't work!! Why?

Comment: i have already sure that i got the correct value from the db, exactly the same name of that resource,

Comment: Then put a breakpoint at the line `int id =.....` and check if you get a valid id and then if this line `String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + id;` is valid

Comment: the id becomes 0

Comment: there for it becomes android.resource://getPackageName()/0

Comment: Are you sure that you stored only the last part of `R.raw.video` meaning `video` in the db? Because if you did and you do have a file `R.raw.video` in the `raw` folder, then the id would not be 0.

Comment: yes i am sure that i stored the exact same name with the video in raw.

Comment: Ok, test this: `int id = getResources().getIdentifier("video", "raw", getPackageName());` instead the one with the variable. Does it return `0` for the id?

Comment: no it is not 0 anymore, a ten digital number and the video was played sucessfully. so weird..

Comment: This proves that you have not stored the right value or you don't get the right value.

Comment: yes i realized the problem.  I get the value from db in this way  `String videoName  Dbhelper.COLUMN_Path;` But what i got is just the name of the table but not the value inside.

Comment: Ok then, change it and try again.

Comment: Good news at last.